# JQUERY Loop dumps all content into first div with a class of .course

Tags: jquery, html, loops, variables, dom

I'm developing a loop with jquery where it:

Finds a Div with a class of "course"
it wraps this div within two other divs "tabs" and "tap"
Then it adds two other HTML Tags: 
and

Every time it cycles through- it takes the first anchor link text- places it into a variable called "accordionID" and sets the ID of the input box as well as the "for" referenced in label.

However when I run the code- it prints out all the content into the first div with a class of "course" instead of going into the div with a class of "course" once, doing all the loop instructions then moving on to the next div with a class of "course". It also sets all the IDs to the very first anchor link text.

What am I missing here?

```js
$(".course").each(function(index) {
  var accordionID = $(".course > a").html()
  $(this).wrap("<div class='tabs'></div>");
  $(this).wrap("<div class='tab'></div>");
  $(this).prepend("<input type= 'checkbox' id='" + accordionID + "-chck1'>");
  $(".course > a").wrap("<label class='tab-label' for='" + accordionID + "-chck1'></label>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="course">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chck1">
      <a href="#">Introductory Module</a>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <ul class="course-setion">
          <li><a href="#1">Faculty Intro Maria</a></li>
          <li><a href="#2">Faculty Intro John</a></li>
          <li><a href="#3">Faculty Intro Laney</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because in the last line of code in the loop you are again using ".course" and not "this". Which means the wrapping and all is happening on the first ".course".

Comment: Perhaps you need to look up .clone

Comment: Several things in your question don't make sense. You are trying to turn "Introductory Module" into an `id`? If so, you can't, there's a space. A better approach would be to use a data attribute with no spaces. What is your goal with doing this?

Comment: I see what you're saying EtemallHour- great observation-

Comment: I'm going to have several accordion divs with a class of course- these will be written withing a CMS- On the CMS side, the client will add a title, and links all wrapped in a div with a class of course. This loop is suppose to find all divs with a class of course- render the appropriate markup- create unique ids for everything that needs an ID- Right now this code works but I have to create a new div with a class other then course- then copy the loop and swap out any mention of course adding in the new class which I know it dumb.